# Django REST - separating valid data from non-valid and serializing the former with many=True

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to come up with a REST api for my app.
In one of my views, I am trying to use `many=True` when initializing my serializer object in order to bulk_insert multiple rows at once. The problem is that if one of the records in the dataset is invalid, serializer's `is_valid()` method return `False`, thus rejecting the entire dataset. Whereas the desired behavior would be inserting valid records and ignoring invalid ones.
I have succeed in achieving this using the following code, but I have a terrible feeling that this is junk code and the REST framework has a native way to do this.

My code below (that I consider junk code :)):

serializers.py

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CalendarEventAttendee
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
def my_view(request):
    validated_data = []
    # Separate valid data from invalid
    for record in request.data:
        if MySerializer(data = record).is_valid():
            validated_data.append(record)

    # bulk_insert valid data    
    serializer = MySerializer(data=validated_data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

Can anyone suggest a better approach ?